# What is "complexity of operation in the worst case" Big-Oh or Big-Omega

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm confused about terminology usage. If people say "complexity of operation in the worst case" what do they mean: lower bound or upper bound?

Answer (score 2):

Most people mean a *tight* bound (i.e. a bound that is both a upper bound and a lower bound), usually given in big Θ (big theta) notation. Many people who only have passing knowledge of the formalism use big O notation, implying an upper bound, but actually mean a tight bound.

Some people restrict themselves to an upper bound because they aren't sure whether their bound is tight.

Virtually nobody discusses lower bounds without explicitly saying so.

Note however that the kind of case (best/average/worst/...) and the kind of bound (upper/lower/tight) is orthogonal: In case X, the complexity is exactly Θ(f(n)), for which there are lower bounds Ω(g1(n)), Ω(g2(n)), etc. and upper bounds O(h1(n)), O(h2(n)), etc. — it is perfectly reasonable to give a lower bound for the worst-case complexity, or an upper bound for the best-case complexity.